# Why won't ADF list the contents of my S3 bucket?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to ingest data from my S3 bucket into Azure via ADF. I added a new connection by entering my Access key ID and Secret access key, and 'Test Connection' against my Service URL (https://myS3BucketName.s3-myRegion.amazonaws.com) works:

[image: Test Connection successful]

However, when I try to browse the contents of my bucket, nothing shows up:

[image: Empty S3 bucket]

From within a VM with the AWS CLI installed, I can use these exact same credentials and list the contents of the bucket successfully:

```bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=myAccessKeyId
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mySecretAccessKey
aws s3 ls s3://myS3BucketName/
```

For the policy associated with this access key, I even granted *all* S3 permissions (even though I already had `GetObject`, `ListBucket`, `GetObjectVersion`, `ListAllMyBuckets`, and more).

How can I best debug this issue? My goal is to do a daily ingestion of files or directories that, in most cases, I will know the exact name of. So if there's a good way to attempt copying of files by exact name without necessarily doing a bucket directory listing, that may be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your troubleshooting approach sounds reasonable, if you can list the content of the bucket using the same credentials through `aws cli`, you should also be able to list the content of the bucket from ADF.
To list the content of the bucket from the ADF, you can use a dataset associated with your S3 linked service, in the dataset you can inform the path and browse your bucket.

[image]

I see you mentioned Service URL, the instructions above normally work without issues for linked services that don't have a service URL specified. Have you tried to test your linked service without it?

[image]

Comment: It turns out that deleting the Service URL allows me to see and copy files. Thank you!